# Is React native useful for experienced native android developer?

Tags: android, react-native

I am in mobile development since last 10 years, and in native android development since last 3 years. I have created 4-5 native android applications. I am very much comfortable with front end development.

Now I have joined a new company which is a start up company. They want to make applications for both android and ios and want me to use React Native. From the earlier documentation of React Native, I got an idea that React Native will be useful for the developers who came from web development background and who have idea about java script and React for Web.

I have never done web development and not even no java script.

So I want to know that React Native will be helpful to those who dont know native, or it really helpful for all?

And how much flexibility it gives if I need to develop some features purely in native?

Thanks in advance,
Krishna

Comment: Off topic but I would love answers from some experienced guys.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure this question should be on SO but anyway, I'm native android dev, recently I started a project using react-native.

What I can say, yes it's cool you can build something quickly even if you don't come from web. But when I'm developing I just have the feeling to do tricky things.

Do this to manage iOS specific thing, do that for android... I don't have the feeling to code something smooth and produce a good code, maybe it's due to my lack of xp with react-native, but I'm really not comfortable to code in that way.
It's probably cool to release quickly an MVP of your app and experiment. But if you plan to build the next billion dollar app which will be maintained long term I would definitely not go with react.

It's only my personal feeling off course. There is plenty articles about the topic very well augmented you should google for it

Comment: I know this is a off topic, but I did not find other place to post this question.  Thank  you so much for your answer.   I am also having the same feeling like yours that for a long term application, this will not be a good idea..

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a fair question. I too had the same 6 months back.

I had all my experience as a native Android dev, but when I joined a startup, I was expected to make an app which should support both Android and iOS. I accepted it and learnt JS and ReactNative.

My thought process was that since I don't know iOS/Swift/Objective-C, I might as well learn JS/ReactNative, as it will not just get the job done but also add a new dimension to my skill-set i.e. not just I would be able to develop apps for Android and iOS but also, given the reputation that React is gathering, open myself to web development if needed in future. It would provide me experience with a completely different paradigm.

But all said and done, I think it's a matter of personal choice.

Answer (score 0):

react native is the great choice for you.
react and reactNative is easy to learn.
However, redux is the garbage.
You should not use redux.
You don't need to state management in a startup(small app).
I recommend using Expo.

Welcome to reactNative.

Answer (score 0):

React Native is a fun environment to build apps in. The hype lies in the cross-platform capabilities, but I would stray from relying on that feature alone since it takes a while to get it working on both anyway (many things differ in implementation).

This is a startup's dream since it can get anything running fairly fast. The stability and dependability of libraries/updates is poor - something most devs understand at the bleeding edge. There are many packages and tools coming out every day, it's a bit nuts.

The hot-reload and debugging tools are fast and mighty helpful.

State management tools are all over the place, but Redux has the most documentation and support by far. I recommend using it if you are going to handle complex state between screens. Some people hate it because it has some complexity in setting up...

Answer (score 0):

I am also Android Native developer have more than 3 years experience, last month I have started React Native There are some pros and cons which I have faced.

Pros:

1. Fast development as compare to Android native
2. Hot reloading is great feature you don't have to wait now for gradle building and reinstalling app
3. JS is easy you will get familiar within a week

Cons

1. You will get frustrated from RED screen in few minutes (No proper logs like in Android Native)
2. Hot reloading feature some times doesn't works perfectly
3. Not stable as compare to Android Native